# Script to automate copy files with a pattern over network

Tags: windows, shell, network-shares, file-transfer

I am trying to automate some tasks... I have to do some development work on one machine and other parts on another machine, with communication through a network share.

I would like to copy certain files, not the entire directories - which may contain lots of additional build items, some large.

Something like

```
set source="C:\Users\me\Documents\sourcefolder"
set dest="\\SHARE\FOLDER\me\destfolder"
xcopy %source%+"*.cpp" %dest%
```

How can I do a command like this ? copy all files with a given pattern (like *.cpp) from source to destination ?

Also - can that be done recursively - for all the folders inside source ?

Edit:

Trying

```
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\sourcefolder\*.cpp" "\\SHARE\FOLDER\me\destfolder\"
```

(first try did not work because I did not know I should make a bat file. Thank you Saggio.)

Still... for best results, for a complex directory structure I would like to be able to use variables and perhaps copy recursively - there are many directories I have to copy over.

Also, the patterns I want to copy are something like "all files with extension .cpp, except those that start with moc_" or ""all files with extension .h, except those that start with ui_"

I could copy then delete the ones hat I don't want I guess... But is there a better way ?

Comment: couldn't you just do `xcopy %source%\*.cpp %dest%`?

Comment: I am trying... so far I get an error about compatibility... and when trying to use the "Compatibility" tab to run, no error but also nothing happens.

Comment: What errors are you seeing specifically?

Comment: why are you creating an executable file?  It looks like `move.exe` is x86 and you're in an x64 environment. Since it's working running it straight from the cmd line, perhaps just create a a `*.bat` file script instead of a full fledged executable?

Comment: @Saggio thank you, now I feel ridiculous... I did not know how to create a windows script...

Comment: is it possible to recurse inside the directories, and also to exclude certain patterns ?

Comment: Yes, see http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html. See `/s` and `/exclude` options

Comment: Looks great but i tried /exclude:"moc_" or /exclude"*moc_*" or even "path\\*moc_*" and each times I get "can't read file "whatever i asked for" ... 0 files copied.  Each file from each directory has a  built file ... a few hunded... the only way I can do this is with glob patterns...

Comment: Take a look at some of these .... https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup

Comment: I'm running a script I made in Python that copies and moves files. The os.walk() module is recursive

Answer (score 1):

Did not list you OS and enviroment
If you can use robocopy
it has all the tools you need to do this depending on your details :

robocopy %source% %dest% *.cpp /s

will copy all cpp files from the source to dest

it includes many other options for automating this task depending on exactly what you want. just do a robocopy /? and it will list them. For example, you can do a test robocopy that only shows what it would have done if it had been for real. 
 /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.